# Does Android Studio support JNI debugging?

Tags: debugging, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I want to debug code written in C. Currently, Android Studio 1.2.2 does not seem to support JNI debugging.
Does Android Studio 1.3 RC 1 version support step over, step into as Java debugger?

Comment: I don't think  Android Studio support this right now. You will have to use gdb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android Studio supports JNI debugging first time with 1.3 RC 1. See [here](http://tools.android.com/recent)

To get started using this feature, go to [add native code](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html).

Check [this repository](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk) for Android NDK samples using the new Android Studio 1.3 preview C++ integration.

Comment: Do not follow the Android NDK Preview listed above. Google has decided to stop doing Gradle Experimental Builds. CMake is the new way, this is obsolete information.

Answer (score 1):

It is supported, but with limitations.

> #### Limitations
>
> First, the Android NDK support only works with the new experimental Gradle plugin for Android (which in turn requires Gradle 2.5).
>
> While the new gradle plugin delivers some major performance improvements (and Android NDK build support), note that it also requires changes to the build file “DSL” (the way your build is described in your build.gradle files.) Not only will you need to modify your build.gradle files (a process we hope to automate before the plugin graduates from experimental to stable), but we anticipate making some additional incompatible changes along the way.
>
> Second, note also that Android Studio has not yet been updated to fully handle the experimental plugin. This means that for example the Project Structure Dialog, and various quick fixes which automatically update the build data, do not work correctly. You’ll need to edit your build.gradle files manually to configure your projects. As another example, the various templates which update the build files (such as New Module), have not yet been updated.
>
> Finally, there are still some known bugs in this build; when debugging with LLDB breakpoints do not always work on Windows; if you run into this, you can switch to GDB debugging as a temporary workaround.

Source: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview

Answer (score 1):

If your native code is wrapped as a library, you need to add this part to your **app's** gradle:

```
model {
    android.sources {
        main {
            jniLibs {
                dependencies {
                    project ":mynativelib" buildType "debug"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```